# ¿Cómo crear un true y false y mostrar dato según su valor - PHP?

Tags: php

Quiero controlar mi sistema en dos procesos en **ejecución** (linea) & **prueba** (demo), mediante variables con valores `true` & `false`

Ejemplo creo una pagina llamada **control** donde mediante un `true` o `false` muestro datos a interés.

Veamos algo simple, si en la variable `$url` es `true` mostrar esta **Urls** `example.com/execute/` pero si es `false` mostrar esta **Urls** `demo.example.com/execute/`

Ahora en algo más complejo/dinámico mediante [array (php)](http://php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php) evitar mostrar un producto controlando mediante la misma características `true` & `false`

```
$a =array(
    1 => 'string1 a',
    2 => 'string2 b',
    3 => 'string3 c',
);
```

veamos si en el producto `$string1` es `true` mostramos el producto resultado `string1 a` pero si es `false` no mostrar el producto no imprimirlo.

**control.php**

```
<?php
  $url = true;
  $string1 = false;
  $string2 = true;
  $string3 = true;
```

Me puede explicar como llevar este proceso.

Intente algo así pero igual sea `true` o `false` se imprime el valor:

```
$a = false;

$a = "h1!";


echo $a;
```

Pero aún así faltaría cosas por ejemplo en la **URLs** se debe mostrar dos valores uno si es falso y otro si es verdadero, en caso del producto ahí es diferente solo mostrar el producto si es verdadero si es falso no mostrar nada.

Comment: Me parece que tu dilema se resolvería con un **[operador ternario](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php)**, aunque no termino de entender del todo lo que quieres. Mira esto: `$a=false;
$estado = ($a) ? $a : $a;
echo $estado;` ahí no se imprime nada. Y si cambias a esto: `$a='hola';
$estado = ($a) ? $a : $a;
echo $estado;` se imprime siempre `hola`  o si quieres imprimir otra cosa, cambias esto, cuando `$a` sea `true`: `$a='hola';
$estado = ($a) ? 'a es true' : $a;`

Comment: @A.Cedano Lo que deseo es controlar toda mi aplicación mediante una pagina llamada control.php en vez de ir a cambiar datos manuales quiero hacerlo por medio de `true` y `false` por ejemplo en la **Urls** si pongo `true` en `$url` mostrar la url verdadera y se pongo `false` mostrar otra url no se si me explico

Comment: Ahí tienes la respuesta: un operador ternario. Si lo que estás evaluando como `true` o `false` se encuentra en `$a`, sería algo así: **`$url=($a) ? 'url verdadera' : 'otra-url'; return $url;`** Ahí recibirás una u otra url según el valor que tenga `$a`, verdadero o falso.

Comment: @A.Cedano No llego a entender muy bien si lo realizo así no me muestra nada `$a = true; $url=($a) ? 'url verdadera' : 'otra-url'; return $url;`

Comment: Te puse el `return` suponiendo que el valor de `$url` lo necesitabas en otra parte. Si cambias el `return $url;` por `echo $url;` verás que sí se imprime.

Comment: @A.Cedano Entiendo pero en el mismo documento no funcionara con el `return` porque si lo hago así no imprime `$a = false;
 
$url=($a) ? 'url verdadera' : 'otra-url';

return $url;
 
echo $url;` si le quito el `return` ahí si funciona.

Comment: El `return` es por si quieres crear una función de validación, que puede estar en el mismo documento o en otro. Es lo que se suele hacer en estos casos, así no tienes que repetir siempre la validación, le envías el valor y la función valida. Lo he explicado al final de mi respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto podría resolverse con un [operador ternario](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php).

Por ejemplo:

```
$a = true; 
$url=($a) ? 'url-verdadera' : 'otra-url'; 
echo $url;
```

**Resultado:**

```
url-verdadera
```

---

```
$a = false; 
$url=($a) ? 'url-verdadera' : 'otra-url'; 
echo $url;
```

**Resultado:**

```
otra-url
```

---

Si lo tienes en una función, mucho mejor:

```
function validarURL($valor)
{
    $url=($valor) ? 'url-verdadera' : 'otra-url'; 
    return $url;
}
```

**Ejemplo de uso:**

```
$myURL="http://www.example.com".validarURL(true);
echo $myURL;
```

**Resultado:**

```
http://www.example.com/url-verdadera
```

Comment: no me había fijado este un ejemplo sencillo, pero en uno más complejo, más dinámico por ejemplo quiero mostrar producto en un `radio` pero también quiero ocultar el radio si es `false` si lo hago tomando el primer ejemplo el texto no se muestra pero el `radio` lo esta imprimiendo como si tuviera un valor ejemplo:

Comment: `$a = false;

$url=($a) ? 'url verdadera' : '';

$a =array(
    1 => ''.$url.'',
    2 => 'string2 b',
    3 => 'string3 c',
);


foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
echo '<input name="radio" type="radio" id="'.$key.'" value="'.$key.'" >';
echo '<label for="'.$key.'" title="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</label>';
}`

Comment: El resultado impreso: `<input name="radio" type="radio" id="1" value="1" ><label for="1" title=""></label><input name="radio" type="radio" id="2" value="2" ><label for="2" title="string2 b">string2 b</label><input name="radio" type="radio" id="3" value="3" ><label for="3" title="string3 c">string3 c</label>` [Resultado en línea](https://jsfiddle.net/0wrya0m7/)

Comment: No se muestra el nombre, pero el `radio` si se imprime...

Comment: @Oscar Claro, porque aunque sea false, tú estás leyendo todos los keys-values del array. Si quieres puedes aplicar la misma lógica del operador ternario dentro del bucle, de ese modo sólo se crearán elementos HTML cuando el valor de cada elemento del array tenga algo. También podrías eliminar los elementos del array que tengan valor falso antes de recorrerlo... hay varias formas de hacer esto.

Comment: Por ejemplo: `$a = false; 
$url=($a) ? 'url verdadera' : false; 
$a =array( 1 => $url, 2 => 'string2 b', 3 => 'string3 c', ); 

$strHTML="";
foreach ($a as $key => $value) 
{ 
    $strHTML.=($value) ? '<input name="radio" type="radio" id="'.$key.'" value="'.$key.'" >'.
                         '<label for="'.$key.'" title="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</label>' 
                       : false;
}
echo $strHTML;`

Comment: Da como resultado: `<input name="radio" type="radio" id="2" value="2" ><label for="2" title="string2 b">string2 b</label><input name="radio" type="radio" id="3" value="3" ><label for="3" title="string3 c">string3 c</label>`