# ¿Cómo mostrar dato si es true en un array?

Tags: php

Encontré el siguiente [post aquí en es.stackoverflow.com](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/115149/c%C3%B3mo-crear-un-true-y-false-y-mostrar-dato-seg%C3%BAn-su-valor-php) sobre como crear un true y false, muy bien explicado, pero como podría habilitar datos `boolean` en un `array` según la especificación mediante `true` or `false`.

Por ejemplo yo tengo el siguiente `array` que me habilita tres formas de pago de manera ordenada según el orden numérico.

```
$MetodoPago = array(
    1 => 'Transferencia Bancaria',
    2 => 'PayPal',
    3 => 'Tarjeta de credito',
);
```

Y, si quiero inhabilitar un método de pago debo cambiar el orden numérico y comentar el método para que no aparezca entre las opciones visibles del usuario por ejemplo.

```
$MetodoPago = array(
    1 => 'Transferencia Bancaria',
    //2 => 'PayPal',
    2 => 'Tarjeta de credito',
);
```

Yo intente lo siguiente como prueba:

```
$CreditCard = false;

$enableCreditCard = $CreditCard ? 'Tarjeta de credito' : false;


$MetodoPago =array(
    1 => 'Transferencia Bancaria',
    2 => $enableCreditCard,
    3 => 'PayPal',

);

foreach ($MetodoPago as $key => $value) {
    print_r($value);
}
```

Esto me da el siguiente resultado:

```
Transferencia BancariaPayPal
```

Parece todo estar bien, pero al momento de imprimir la variable `$key` mediante `print_r($key);` me muestra el siguiente resultado:

```
123
```

Entonces mi pregunta es la siguiente como generar los números en orden `123` y inhabilitar tanto el número como el texto según el dato `boolean` para así tener el siguiente resultado:

```
print_r($value)
Transferencia BancariaPayPal

....
print_r($key);
12
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes usar una función auxiliar para eliminar del *array* aquellos elementos cuyo *valor* sea `false`:

```
function myArrayFilter( &$arr ) {
  foreach( $arr as $key => $value )
    if( !$value ) unset( $arr[$key] );
}
```

Observa que pasamos el *array* por referencia ( `&` ) para poder moficarlo.

Con esa función añadida, tu código quedaría así:

```
$CreditCard = false;

$enableCreditCard = $CreditCard ? 'Tarjeta de credito' : false;

$MetodoPago = [
  1 => 'Transferencia Bancaria',
  2 => $enableCreditCard,
  3 => 'PayPal',
);

myArrayFilter( $MetodoPago );

foreach( $MetodoPago as $key => $value ) {
  print_r( $value );
}
```

Comment: funciona perfectamente gracias :)